# Highchart Dates in data

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

i m working on highcharts i need to show the graph having starting and ending date like low date is 2013-08-10 and high date is 2013-08-20 with different colors each line, i have done with the numbers but cant do with dates can any one help me??

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Initiatives',
        data: [{ 
            x: 0,
            y: ['2013-08-4','2013-08-16'],
            fillColor: "red"
        },{
            x: 1,
            y: ['2013-08-2','2013-09-9'],
            fillColor: "blue"
        }]
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot dats, you can use the javascript Date.UTC function:

```
 y: [Date.UTC(2013,7,4),Date.UTC(2013,7,16)],
```

Note, the Javascript months start at zero, to August is 7.

You should try something like:

```
        data: [{ 
            x: 0,
                     low:Date.UTC(2013,7,4),
                     high:Date.UTC(2013,7,16),
            color: "red"
        },{
            x: 1,
                     low: Date.UTC(2013,7,2),
                     high:Date.UTC(2013,8,9),
            color: "blue"
        }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x4gQp/

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to plot. Can you describe what you want to plot, or show us a fiddle of something similar ?

Answer (score 0):

In highcharts, you can also do the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

```
series: [{
    name: 'Initiatives',
    data: [{ 
        x: 0,
        y: [1375574400000, 1376611200000],
        fillColor: "red"
    },{
        x: 1,
        y: [1375401600000, 1378684800000],
        fillColor: "blue"
    }]
}]
```

This is useful if you're generating the chart data in another language.

In ruby for example, it's easy: `Date.parse('2013-09-9').strftime('%Q')`